# How to change style of items in ListView onClick in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom adapter for a listview with a custom view.

Now I would like to change background of the listview items (bg color of layout in the custom view of an item) as I press a button.

Is it even possible? Is it possible to change for all listview items at once or I have to change one by one?

Comment: Visit the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107440/onlistviewitemclick-view-argument-refer-to-multiple-listitems/12107917#12107917

Comment: As I said. I am not clicking on the item. I am click on a button. Therefore I am not receiving the item `view` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
ListView mView;
...
int c = mView.getChildCount()
for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
   View v = mView.getChildAt(i);
   v.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

As far as I know there is no way to set color for all child view. And if it would, there will be still iteration across all views in background.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking about that as well. I guess that's the only option.

Answer (score 0):

if you have inflated the "listitems" using "customview" then just bind the elements(e.g.: button) of customview in custom adapter and set the onclick listeners for them.

you can refer this: [preserve state of elements inside listview's each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269463/preserve-state-of-elements-inside-listviews-each-row)

In the my custom adapter,I have bind 1 TextView and 2 Buttons of my custom view and then implemented on click listeners.

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to iterating over all children, you can do the color change in the binder and force the ListView to rebind the items (via the data change methods in the adapter). That way, you're not poking inside the ListView's view hierarchy, which is generally considered really bad practice.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?